# GLSL Shaders using Processing Pi on a Pi 3 B+

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, glsl, processing, shader

It’s the first time I’m porting over a GLSL shader from Processing OSX to run on Processing Pi running on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I have a very basic shader that dissolves between two videos playing. It runs totally fine on my mac but when it’s ported to Processing Pi and updated to use the Processing video library GLvideo instead it is throwing an error.

The shader was originally converted from a ShaderToy post but I re-wrote it to straight GLSL  to make sure there wasn't any compatibility issues. I looked around and wasn’t able to find anything specific that I think would cause this problem. So any references, pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried a few other things, I resized the videos to be smaller, updated the Pi’s GPU memory to 256mb etc. I ensured it still works on OSX, but when it’s run on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ the sketch is an empty white screen.

I thought that maybe there's something different with how the Pi handles GLSL? Or if there's a limitation on the sampler2D textures in the Pi GPU? More so on the processing side, it crossed my Perhaps there’s no support to set PGraphics from Processing to a sampler2D texture in the shader on processing pi? maybe there's something with GLVideo images when you set a texture3D. Also, maybe it’s the I’m mixing up something between how frag and color shaders work. At the moment I think I’m using a Processing Color Shader.

The only output in the console is:

```
Final caps: video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)640, height=(int)360, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
Final caps: video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)640, height=(int)360, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)25/1, texture-target=(string)2D
```

**shaderDisolveGLSL.pde**

```
//import processing.video.*;
import gohai.glvideo.*;

PShader mixShader;  

PGraphics pg;
PGraphics pg2;

//Movie movie;
//Movie movie2;

GLMovie movie;
GLMovie movie2;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P2D);
  noSmooth();
  pg = createGraphics(640, 360, P2D);

  //movie = new Movie(this, "_sm/LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4");
  movie = new GLMovie(this, "_sm/LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4");
  movie.loop();

  //movie2 = new Movie(this, "_sm/LabspaceFireblur2.mp4");
  movie2 = new GLMovie(this, "_sm/LabspaceFireblur2.mp4");
  movie2.loop();

  pg = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);
  pg2 = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);

  mixShader = loadShader("fadeshader.glsl");
  mixShader.set("iResolution", float(width), float(height));
  mixShader.set("iTime", millis()/1000.);

  mixShader.set("iChannel0", pg);
  mixShader.set("iChannel1", pg2);

}  

//void movieEvent(Movie m) {
void movieEvent(GLMovie m) {
  m.read();
  redraw();
}

void draw() {

  pg.beginDraw();
    pg.image(movie, 0, 0, width, height);
  pg.endDraw();

  pg2.beginDraw();
    pg2.image(movie2, 0, 0, width, height);
  pg2.endDraw();

  shader(mixShader);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

}
```

**fadeshader.glsl**

```
// Type of shader expected by Processing
#define PROCESSING_COLOR_SHADER

uniform float iTime;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;
uniform sampler2D iChannel1;
uniform vec2 iResolution;

void main() {

    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 mixColor = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 color0 = vec4(uv.x,uv.y,0.0,1.0);
    vec4 color1 = vec4(uv.x,uv.y,0.0,1.0);

    color0 = texture2D(iChannel0, uv);
    color1 = texture2D(iChannel1, uv);

    float duration = 10.0;
    float t = mod(float(iTime), duration) / duration;

    mixColor = mix(color0, color1, t);
    gl_FragColor = mixColor;
}
```

I’ve updated a new version of the sample sketch with the smaller videos here if anyone was curious: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fu2plxmqhf7shtp/AADxqmW9zf73EsdzworCb5ECa?dl=0

Any recommendations, or thoughts as to what might be up or where to start debugging some more would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but the error might be related to video encoding and what the GLVideo library can decode on Raspberry PI (relying on gstreamer)

I'm already running into errors on OSX on my old system: sketch freezes on a gray screen for a few seconds then crashes without any warnings or errors.

I recommend re-encoding the videos, dropping audio channel if it's not required and using the same or similar H.264 encoder as what the Processing transit video (e.g. Examples > Libraries > Video > Movie > Loop)

```
ffprobe -i /Users/George/Desktop/shaderDisolveGLSL/data/_sm/LabspaceDawn\ v1\ blur\ 2.mp4 
ffprobe version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/George/Desktop/shaderDisolveGLSL/data/_sm/LabspaceDawn v1 blur 2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2020-03-15T14:03:48.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:49.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 218 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 119 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-15T14:03:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 03/15/2020.
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 95 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-15T14:03:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 03/15/2020.
```

transit video details:

```
ffprobe -i /Users/George/Desktop/shaderDisolveGLSL/data/transit.mov 
ffprobe version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/George/Desktop/shaderDisolveGLSL/data/transit.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2012-08-31T20:17:39.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:12.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 731 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x360, 727 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-08-31T20:17:44.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
```

What seems to work:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x360, 727 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
```

What seems to crash:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 119 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
```

I've ran into some other intermitent JOGL errors when using `movieEvent`: sneaking `.read()` calls in `draw()` seems to resolve the issue.

Here's a tweaked version of your code I did manage to run on OSX:

```
import processing.video.*;
//import gohai.glvideo.*;

PShader mixShader;  

PGraphics pg;
PGraphics pg2;

Movie movie;
Movie movie2;

//GLMovie movie;
//GLMovie movie2;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P2D);
  noSmooth();
  noStroke();

  //movie = new Movie(this, "_sm/LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4");
  movie = new Movie(this, "transit.mov");
  //movie = new GLMovie(this, "_sm/LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4");
  movie.loop();

  //movie2 = new Movie(this, "_sm/LabspaceFireblur2.mp4");
  movie2 = new Movie(this, "transit2.mov");
  //movie2 = new GLMovie(this, "_sm/LabspaceFireblur2.mp4");
  movie2.loop();

  pg = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);
  pg2 = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);

  mixShader = loadShader("fadeshader.glsl");
  mixShader.set("iResolution", float(width), float(height));
  mixShader.set("iChannel0", pg);
  mixShader.set("iChannel1", pg2);

}  

//void movieEvent(Movie m) {
//void movieEvent(GLMovie m) {
  //m.read();
  //redraw();
//}

void draw() {
  if(movie.available()){   movie.read(); }
  if(movie2.available()){   movie2.read(); }
  
  pg.beginDraw();
    // for testing only since both movies are the same
    movie.filter(GRAY);
    pg.image(movie, 0, 0, width, height);
  pg.endDraw();

  pg2.beginDraw();
    pg2.image(movie2, 0, 0, width, height);
  pg2.endDraw();
  
  // don't forget to update time
  mixShader.set("iTime", millis() * 0.01);
  
  shader(mixShader);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Hopefully this works with the transit mov on Raspberry Pi to test codecs.
Once that runs smoothly, re-encode your videos (Handbreak might help with that) and try again.

@jshaw3 I had a change to test on a RPI3. There seems to be a problem with the GLVideo. If you don't require audio you might be able to get away with an image sequence instead: [Image Sequence Player](https://github.com/hirschandmann/image-sequence-player) could make this easier. Bare in mind this should initialise in less than 5 seconds to avoid a timeout on the P3D/GL side (otherwise defer loading to the first frames):

```
import com.hirschandmann.image.*;

PShader mixShader;  

PGraphics pg;
PGraphics pg2;

ISPlayer movie1;
ISPlayer movie2;

boolean loadTriggered = false;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P2D);
  noSmooth();
  pg = createGraphics(640, 360, P2D);

  pg = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);
  pg2 = createGraphics(width, height, P2D);

  mixShader = loadShader("fadeshader.glsl");
  mixShader.set("iResolution", float(width), float(height));
  mixShader.set("iTime", millis()/1000.);

  mixShader.set("iChannel0", pg);
  mixShader.set("iChannel1", pg2);

}  

void draw() {
 
  if(!loadTriggered){
    movie1 = new ISPlayer(this,dataPath("_sm/LabspaceDawnv1blur2Frames"));
    movie1.loop();
    
    movie2 = new ISPlayer(this,dataPath("_sm/LabspaceFireblur2Frames"));
    movie2.loop();
    
    loadTriggered = true;
  }
  
  pg.beginDraw();
    if(movie1 != null) pg.image(movie1, 0, 0, width, height);
  pg.endDraw();

  pg2.beginDraw();
    if(movie2 != null) pg2.image(movie2, 0, 0, width, height);
  pg2.endDraw();
  
  shader(mixShader);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  
}
```

**Note** the above assumes you've converted the .mp4 files to image sequences (e.g. `LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4` -> `LabspaceDawnv1blur2Frames`). Here's an ffmepg example:

```
ffmpeg -i LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4.mp4 -vf fps=1/60 LabspaceDawnv1blur2.mp4Frames/frame_%04d.png
```